# Why is table being updated with NULL for foreign key?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have a table called `Paychecks` that contains 294 rows. I've created a new table called `TaxableEmployerPaidItems`. Its primary key is a foreign key to `Paychecks`.

I am iterating over `Paychecks` and inserting a row into `TaxableEmployerPaidItems` for each row in `Paychecks`, then updating the foreign key. 294 rows are inserted into `TaxableEmployerPaidItems` as I would expect.

In `Paychecks`, the first 114 rows contain foreign keys to `TaxableEmployerPaidItems`, then after the 114th row all foreign keys are NULL.

Why would this be happening?

This is the code in my stored procedure:

```
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @RowCnt INT
    DECLARE @TaxableEmployerPaidItemsIDInserted  INT

    SET @RowCnt = (SELECT COUNT(PaycheckID) FROM [dbo].[Paychecks])

    DECLARE @I INT
    SET @I = 1 

    -- LOOP through rows of dbo.Paychecks
    WHILE (@I <= @RowCnt)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[TaxableEmployerPaidItems]
                (Item1Amount, Item1Description, Item2Amount, Item2Description, Item3Amount, Item3Description, Deleted)
        VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0)

        UPDATE [dbo].[Paychecks] 
        SET TaxableEmployerPaidItemsId = @@IDENTITY 
        WHERE PaycheckID = @I

        SET @I = @I + 1
    END
END
```

Comment: Are all 294 IDs sequential with no gaps? You realise you could do this without a loop, by using the `output` clause.

Comment: Yes, no gaps. I will look up the output clause. I haven't used it before. Thanks.

Comment: Also `scope_identity()` is better than `@@identity`.

Comment: Anyway, I can't reproduce your situation https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a786b77c74d660f7efc646aee5bb96c0 - there must be something else going on. Do you have any triggers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue isn't reproducible as presented (see this [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a786b77c74d660f7efc646aee5bb96c0)). However you don't want to be doing this sort of thing in a loop. SQL is a set based language so you should therefore be attempting to solve your problem in a set based manner before reverting to a loop. In this case you just need to make use of the [`MERGE` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and the [`OUTPUT` clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

```
create table #NewId (id int, OtherId int);

merge dbo.PaidItems with (holdlock) as Target
using dbo.Paychecks as Source
on 1 = 0 -- force insert
when not matched by Target
  then insert (Item1Amount, Item1Description, Item2Amount, Item2Description, Item3Amount, Item3Description, Deleted)
       values (NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,0)
output Inserted.PaidItemID, Source.PaycheckID into #NewId (id, OtherId);

update P set
  TaxableEmployerPaidItemsId = N.id
from dbo.Paychecks P
inner join #NewId N on N.OtherId = P.PaycheckID;

drop table #NewId;
```

The reason you need a `MERGE` rather than an `INSERT` is because only in a `MERGE` are you able to access source table columns in the `OUTPUT` clause.

Note: If you find yourself at some point needing to use `@@IDENTITY` then in most cases you are safer using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`.

More info on [`MERGE`](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/) including why to use the locking hint `WITH (HOLDLOCK)`.

Comment: .... with(HOLDLOCK) ........